# Maximum value of typedefed signed type

Tags: c, math

I was reading [John Regehr's blog](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1208) on how he gives his students an assignment about saturating arithmetic.  The interesting part is that the code has to compile as-is while using typedefs to specify different integer types, see the following excerpt of the [full header](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5785/hw2/sat_ops.h):

```
typedef signed int mysint;
//typedef signed long int mysint;

mysint sat_signed_add (mysint, mysint);

mysint sat_signed_sub (mysint, mysint);
```

The corresponding unsigned version is simple to implement (although I'm actually not sure if padding bits wouldn't make that problematic too), but I actually don't see how I can get the maximum (or minimum) value of an unknown signed type in C, without using macros for `MAX_` und `MIN_` or causing undefined behavior.

Am I missing something here or is the assignment just flawed (or more likely I'm missing some crucial information he gave his students)?

Comment: the limits.h file contains all the limits that you would need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this without making assumptions or invoking implementation-defined (not necessarily *un*defined) behavior.  If you assume that there are no padding bits in the representation of `mysint` or of `uintmax_t`, however, then you can compute the maximum value like this:

```
mysint mysint_max = (mysint)
    ((~(uintmax_t)0) >> (1 + CHAR_BITS * (sizeof(uintmax_t) - sizeof(mysint))));
```

The minimum value is then either `-mysint_max` (sign/magnitude or ones' complement) or `-mysint_max - 1` (two's complement), but it is a bit tricky to determine which.  You don't know *a priori* which bit is the sign bit, and there are possible trap representations that differ for different representations styles.  You also must be careful about evaluating expressions, because of the possibility of "the usual arithmetic conversions" converting values to a type whose representation has different properties than those of the one you are trying to probe.

Nevertheless, you can distinguish the type of negative-value representation by computing the bitwise negation of the `mysint` representation of `-1`.  For two's complement the `mysint` value of the result is `0`, for ones' complement it is `1`, and for sign/magnitude it is `mysint_max - 1`.

If you add the assumption that all signed integer types have the same kind of negative-value representation then you can simply perform such a test using an ordinary expression on default `int` literals.  You don't need to make that assumption, however.  Instead, you can perform the operation directly on the type representation's bit pattern, via a `union`:

```
union mysint_bits {
    mysint i;
    unsigned char bits[sizeof(mysint)];
} msib;

int counter = 0;

for (msib.i = -1; counter < sizeof(mysint); counter += 1) {
    msib.bits[counter] = ~msib.bits[counter];
}
```

As long as the initial assumption holds (that there are no padding bits in the representation of type `mysint`) `msib.i` must then be a valid representation of the desired result.

Comment: It's implementation defined whether ones'-complement all-ones is negative zero or a trap. So I think `mysint_bits.i == 0` could raise an implementation-defined signal. In some wierd non-existent-but-theoretically-compliant architecture. :)

Comment: @rici, you're right, darn.  I looked this up, but apparently did not read fully.

Comment: Edited to document an additional assumption about trap representations.

Comment: Edited to add a work-around for the trap representation issue.

Comment: Final edit, providing a simpler detection algorithm for the signed integer representation with no additional assumptions.

Comment: Note: if you need to allow for the possibility that the representation of type `mysint` has padding bits, then I think it is impossible to reliably compute what representation is used, because you cannot safely assume *anything* about the values of the padding bits.  You could possibly apply an heuristic approach to determining the properties of the type, but whatever conclusion you reach heuristically can turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: That's very clever. But I argue that padding is more likely than non-2s-comp. First, there are various padding bit scenarios. eg. tagged-value VM architectures where some bit(s) encode type information, eg. erlang 28/60 bit integers or many lisp/scheme/smalltalk VMs. Second, suppose you had 1s-comp or s/m hardware. Since unsigned arithmetic must obey 2s-comp logic, the cheapest solution is to use native signed datatypes, forcing the sign bit to be 0 (that is, turn it into a padding bit), which is legal. That doesn't affect your second solution, since it only applies to uintmax_t.

Comment: @rici, I don't disagree, but we've both observed that assumptions must be made.  If you don't assume anything about padding bits and you don't know the unsigned type corresponding to `mysint`, then I don't think you can compute the maximum `mysint` value, regardless of representation.

Comment: In fact, computing the maximum value of type `mysint` requires an assumption about padding even if you *do* know the corresponding unsigned type.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a way to determine the largest and smallest representable values for an unknown signed integer type in C, without knowing something more. (In C++, you have `std::numeric_limits` available, so it is trivial.)

The largest representable value for an unsigned integer type is `(myuint)(-1)`. That is guaranteed to work independent of padding bits, because (§ 6.3.1.3/1-2):

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type… if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

So to convert `-1` to an unsigned type, you add one more than the maximum representable value to it, and that result must be the maximum representable value. (The standard makes it clear that the meaning of "repeatedly adding or subtracting" is mathematical.)

Now, if you knew that the number of padding bits in the signed type was the same as the number of padding bits in the unsigned type [but see below], you could compute the largest representable signed value from the largest representable unsigned value:

```
(mysint)( (myuint)(-1) / (myuint)2 )
```

Unfortunately, that's not enough to compute the minimum representable signed value, because the standard permits the minimum to be either one less than the negative of the maximum (2's-complement representation) or exactly the negative of the maximum (1's-complement or sign/magnitude representations).

Moreover, the standard does not actually guarantee that the number of padding bits in the signed type is the same as the number of padding bits in the unsigned type. All it guarantees is that the number of *value* bits in the signed type be no greater than the number of value bits in the unsigned type. In particular, it would be legal for the unsigned type to have one more padding bit than the corresponding signed type, in which case they would have the same number of value bits and the maximum representable values would be the same. [Note: a value bit is neither a padding bit nor the sign bit.]

In short, if you knew (for example by being told) that the architecture were 2's-complement and that corresponding signed and unsigned types had the same number of padding bits, then you could certainly compute both signed min and max:

```
myuint max_myuint = (myuint)(-1);
mysint max_mysint = (mysint)(max_myuint / (my_uint)2);
mysint min_mysint = (-max_mysint) - (mysint)1;
```

Finally, casting an out-of-range unsigned integer to a signed integer is *not* undefined behaviour, although most other signed overflows are. The conversion, as indicated by §6.3.1.3/3, is *implementation-defined* behaviour:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Implementation-defined behaviour is required to be documented by the implementation. So, suppose we knew that the implementation was `gcc`. Then we could examine the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation), where we would read the following, in the section "C Implementation-defined behaviour":

- *Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and
   magnitude, two's complement, or one's complement, and whether the
   extraordinary value is a trap representation or an ordinary value
   (C99 6.2.6.2).*

  GCC supports only two's complement integer types, and all bit
   patterns are ordinary values.
- *The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a
   signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an
   object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 6.3.1.3).*

  For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo
   2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Knowing that signed integers are 2s-complement and that unsigned to signed conversions will not trap, but will produce the expected pattern of low-order bits, we can find the maximum and minimum values for any signed type starting with the maximum representable value for the widest unsigned type, `uintmax_t`:

```
uintmax_t umax = (uintmax_t)(-1);
while ( (mysint)(umax) < 0 ) umax >>= 1;
mysint max_mysint = (mysint)(umax);
mysint min_mysint = (-max_mysint) - (mysint)1;
```

Comment: Note that although the assignment the OP referenced provides (presumably) corresponding signed and unsigned types, the actual question refers strictly to determining the characteristics of a `typedef`-obscured signed type.  Perhaps you would consider amending your excellent answer to discuss the case where the corresponding unsigned type is not known?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: OK, this time I tested it. I don't really like the loop, but I don't yet see a better solution; I'm going to walk out the door again and see if this time the right solution comes to mind instead of a bug report :)

Comment: Look a couple of answers down for one way to do this without the loop, under assumptions consistent with, but less strict than, "the compiler is GCC".  :)

Comment: Well I had a hard time to decide between both yours and @JohnBollingers excellent answer, so I decided to give you the bounty for also including quotes from the standard and GCC documentation while accepting John's answer. I hope everybody can live with that :)
PS: Also very interesting tidbit about converting unsigned to signed integers not causing undefined behavior in case of overflow, learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion for getting the `MAX` value of a specific type set with `typedef` without using any library

```
typedef signed int mysint;
mysint size; // will give the size of the type
size=sizeof(mysint)*(mysint)8-(mysint)1; // as it is signed so a bit
                                        // will be deleted for sign bit
mysint max=1;//start with first bit
while(--size)
{
   mysint temp;
   temp=(max<<(mysint)1)|(mysint)1;// set all bit to 1
   max=temp;
}
/// max will contain the max value of the type mysint
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume eight-bit `char`s and a two's complement representation (both reasonable on all modern hardware, with the exception of some embedded DSP stuff), then you just need to form an unsigned integer (use `uintmax_t` to make sure it's big enough) with `sizeof(mysint)*8 - 1` 1's in the bottom bits, then cast it to `mysint`. For the minimum value, negate the maximum value and subtract one.

If you don't want to assume those things, then it's still possible, but you'll need to do some more digging through limits.h to compensate for the size of chars and the sign representation.

Comment: Even if the hardware uses two's complement, modern compilers are more than willing to screw you over if you invoke undefined behavior. E.g. `bool overflows(int a) { return a + 1 < a; }` will be optimized to `return false;`

Comment: You could btw use `CHAR_BIT` to avoid reliance on 8 bit chars, not that it helps in this case though.

Comment: @Voo That's why you do it in an unsigned context. Overflow is well-defined on unsigned integers (though this approach doesn't even use that).

Comment: Fair point, got distracted from your first sentence, sorry. Seems to be a valid way to get the maximum, but is "take the maximum, negate it and subtract 1" really defined? Considering that one's complement would be valid representation, I'm not so sure (also when do I cast the unsigned to signed?)

Comment: @Voo No, it's not valid with sign-magnitude or one's complement. That's why you need to do some extra work if you're not assuming two's complement. I guess an interesting trick would be to use the difference between `INT_MAX` and `-INT_MIN`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the standard does not require that all signed integer types use the same style of negative-value representation, so the difference between `INT_MIN` and `-INT_MAX` (and it has to be that, not the other way around) is definitive only about the representation of `int`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That would be... a pretty weird architecture. And while the standard doesn't explicitly require it, it's clearly written to assume that a given implementation has a single representation for signed integers. The more pressing concern is padding bits.

Comment: @Sneftel: But how do you compute the difference between `INT_MAX` and `-INT_MIN` (or as JohnBollinger says, `INT_MIN` and `-INT_MAX`)? Obviously, you can't compute that with signed `int` arithmetic. You could use `intmax_t`, but I don't believe that is required to be any bigger than `int`. You could play some games to convert them to `uintmax_t`, but there is no guarantee that `uintmax_t` can represent values larger than the largest positive value represented by `intmax_t`. (That is, it could have one more padding bit than the signed type. That's plausible for a non-2's-complement machine.)

Comment: It would at least be a weird C implementation.  There is no requirement, however, that all integer data types supported by a given C implementation correspond to native numeric formats of the underlying architecture (consider many systems' support for 64-bit integer types on 32-bit architectures, for example).  In any case, if you want to avoid implementation-defined behavior (in addition to undefined behavior) then you have to account for the possibility of weird implementations.

Comment: @rici `INT_MAX + INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 0):

*I guess this should work irrespective of negative number representation*

```
// MSB is 1 and rests are zero is minimum number in both 2's and 1's
// compliments representations.
mysint min =  (1 << (sizeof(mysint) * 8 - 1));
mysint max = ~x;
```